# Where did the Imam stand for leading congregational prayers in the masjid al-Haram (in the early days of Islam)?

Tags: hadith, history, masjid-al-haram

As we know because of the tawaf and the fact that the Kaaba which is in the midlle of the mosque is our prayer direction, it is impossible to lead and pray in one single direction in the masjid al-Haram. Therefore mostly the Imam whom leads the prayers nowadays either stays far enough away from the Kaaba or even leads the prayer from one of the floors of the builinding (at least this is what one sees i.e. on TV).

I'm curious if there are any ahadith or narrations telling a special place where the Imam used to stand when leading prayers in the early days of Islam.

There should be narrations as we know that our Prophet () performed Hajj and even prayed in Mekka before the hijra, if not many sahaba () later reside in Mekka, maybe we have narrations about a certain place they recommended ...

Therefore and to sum up my question is:

Where did the Imam stand for leading congregation prayer in the masjid al-Haram (in the early days of Islam)? Please consider providing evidences when answering!

Comment: You should note that at the time of Rasulullah and Abu Bakr (RA) there wasn't a wall around the Kaaba and the building of it was introduced by Umar ibn al Khattab and then added onto by Uthman and the later caliphates.

Comment: @أرمان i read about that, but that still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It wasn't meant to answer the question but help you find the answer by knowing that the circumstances were different in the early days of Islam.